# Got 200 success in header bar but preview and response bar showing nothing in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making rest call in angularjs project

```
$http.get(url)
.then(function(response) {.....}
....
...
```

I am checkiing Network tab in chrome browser.. 
Some time, i am getting 200 success in header bar but same time preview and response bar showing empty(It seems, browser is in progress)

Is this based on BW of network?
Or
Huge Response data?
or
Page Rendering Problem?

Comment: We could use the request you are making, likely something is wrong with its response.

Comment: What do you see on Timing tab? Does it say the request is still in progress? What do you see when you write the response to console after resolving it?

Comment: getting CAUTION: request is not finished yet! in timing bar

Comment: What are you returning? Is it JSON or a file?

Comment: passing json data only and response size is arounf 300KB